# is there any way in python to create list using key value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

how to create a list of key value pairs in python???

I have these two lists:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [11,12,13,14,15]
```

I have tried this code:

```
l = {i:{'x': x[i], 'y': y[i]} for i in range(len(x))}
print(l)
```

output I am getting:

```
{0: {'x': 1, 'y': 11}, 1: {'x': 2, 'y': 12}, 2: {'x': 3, 'y': 13}, 3: {'x': 4, 'y': 14}, 4: {'x': 5, 'y': 15}}
```

expected output:

```
[0: {'x': 1, 'y': 11}, 1: {'x': 2, 'y': 12}, 2: {'x': 3, 'y': 13}, 3: {'x': 4, 'y': 14}, 4: {'x': 5, 'y': 15}]
```

Comment: Your expected output is *not a valid Python data structure*, so it is not clear what you actually expect.

Comment: Lists do not have "key value pairs". `dict` objects do.

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: You could use l = [{'x': x[i], 'y': y[i]} for i in range(len(x))] if you just mean to store the key/value pairs in a list rather than in a dict

Comment: this may make more sense: l = [{i:{'x': x[i], 'y': y[i]}} for i in range(len(x))], trying to guess your output...

Comment: your first output is the right way, lists are positional, so in this case the first dict has `0` as key, this  is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [11,12,13,14,15]

l = [{i:{'x': x[i], 'y': y[i]}}for i in range(len(x))]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to the expected output is an array which contains dictionaries it would look like this.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [11,12,13,14,15]
array = []
for i in len(x):
    array.append({'x' : x[i], 'y' : y[i]})
```

Output will be:

```
[{'x': 1, 'y': 11}, {'x': 2, 'y': 12}]
```

You can access an element like this:

```
array[0]['x'] = 1
array[1]['y'] = 12
```

Comment: @ MisbahAsif Lists *do not have keys*. They have *indexes*, which are positional. So if you want a *list* of key/value pairs, it will look like this: `[{'x': 1, 'y': 11}, {'x': 2, 'y': 12}, ...]`. The indexes are unique because there can at most one element of the list with a given index.